# In Genesis 6:4 how should נְפִילִים (nephilim/giants) be translated?

Tags: hebrew, word-study, hebrew-bible, kjv

Are there other translations of the word "Giant"?  Please note that this question is related to [this question](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/27093/noahs-flood-and-giants).

**Genesis 6:4 KJV**

> There were **giants** in the earth in those days; and also after that,
>   when the sons of God came in unto the daughters of men, and they bare
>   children to them, the same became mighty men which were of old, men of
>   renown.

**1 Chronicles 20:8 KJV**

> These were born unto the **giant** in Gath; and they fell by the hand of
>   David, and by the hand of his servants.

**Numbers 13:33 KJV**

> And there we saw the **giants**, the sons of Anak, which come of the
>   **giants**: and we were in our own sight as grasshoppers, and so we were
>   in their sight.

**Joshua 15:8 KJV**

> And the border went up by the valley of the son of Hinnom unto the
>   south side of the Jebusite; the same is Jerusalem: and the border went
>   up to the top of the mountain that lieth before the valley of Hinnom
>   westward, which is at the end of the valley of the **giants** northward:

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there an English equivalent for Nephilim of Genesis 6:4?](https://hermeneutics.stackexchange.com/questions/83/is-there-an-english-equivalent-for-nephilim-of-genesis-64)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

### Short Answer: "Generally it is the only *translation*" (but it is complicated)

First, there are two (three?) different words in the references you give. The Nephilim (נְפִילִים; a word only ever found in plural form in OT) only appears three times in Gen 6:4 and Num 13:33 (twice). The word in 1 Ch 20:8 (also 1 Ch 20:6 and 1 Ch 8:2; cf. also 1 Ch 4:12) is Rapha (רָפָא; singular), also only found these three times (though that depends on interpretation of homonyms, see below). In Josh 15:8 is the word Rephaim (רְפָאִים; plural), which is always found its eight times (also Josh 18:16; 2 Sam 5:18, 22; 23:13; Isa 17:5; 1 Ch 11:15; 14:9) in connection with the word for valley, Emeq (עֵמֶק), hence in the translations either translated "valley of giants" or transliterated "valley of Rephaim."

Second, many major lexicons essentially uphold the word "giant(s)" as the translation in these spots, though you will find some differences as to what "giant" even should "mean." Many choose not to *translate* the words because of issues in knowing what translation is best, and so they *transliterate* the Hebrew sounds into English (hence, Nephilim and Rephaim).

### Of the Nephilim (נְפִילִים):

**(1) *The Hebrew and Aramaic Lexicon of the Old Testament*** (Ludwig Koehler, Walter Baumgartner, M. E. J. Richardson, and Johann Jakob Stamm) gives some varying thoughts on the word:

> **giants**, arising from miscarriages or hurled down from heaven (Koehler
>   Mensch 38) :: H. Gese Vom Sinai zum Zion (1974):11047: those who have
>   fallen heroically in a battle, the giant-like early inhabitants of
>   Palestine Nu 1333aβ (gloss, which links them with the עֲנָקִים, GnAp
>   2:1; Fitzmyer GenAp2 81), with a mythical origin Gn 64, Sept. γίγαντες
>   (A. Schmitt ZAW 86 (1974):152f); Morgenstern HUCA 14:76ff; Albright
>   Steinzeit 295; Humbert Fschr. W. Vischer 70ff, 76; Reicke-R. Hw. 1601;
>   Stolz BZAW 118 (1970):97; Westermann BK 1:510f.

**(2) *Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon*** (Francis Brown, Samuel Rolles Driver, and Charles Augustus Briggs) essentially just gives "**giants**" with no real expanded commentary.

**(3) *Gesenius’ Hebrew and Chaldee Lexicon to the Old Testament Scriptures.*** (Wilhelm Gesenius and Samuel Prideaux Tregelles) gives more discussion, but also a key point about etymology (emphasis added), which explains some variation of opinion on what "giant" refers to:

> **giants**, Gen. 6:4; Nu. 13:33. So all the ancient versions (Chald.
>   נִפְלָא the giant in the sky, i.e. the constellation Orion, plur. the
>   greater constellations). **The etymology of this word is uncertain**. Some
>   have compared نَبِيلُ, نَبِيلَةُ, which Gigg. and Cast. render, great,
>   large in body; but this is incorrect; for it means, excellent, noble,
>   skilful. I prefer with the Hebrew interpreters and Aqu. (ἐπιπίπτοντες)
>   falling on, attacking, so that נָפִיל is of intransitive
>   signification. Those who used to interpret the passage in Genesis of
>   the fall of the angels, were accustomed to render נפילים fallers,
>   rebels, apostates.

**(4) *Dictionary of Biblical Languages with Semantic Domains: Hebrew (Old Testament)*** (James Swanson) notes the theological debate specifically (of which there are other variations than the two he notes):

> **Nephilim**: a renown race of **giants** (Ge 6:4; Nu 13:33+), note: whether
>   this race was a spirit-human race, or godly-ungodly race is debated
>   among theologians

**(5) Article “1393 נפל.” (Milton C. Fisher) in *Theological Wordbook of the Old Testament* (Edited by R. Laird Harris, Gleason L. Archer Jr., and Bruce K. Waltke) gives more discussion about that uncertain etymology:

> **giants**, **the Nephilim** (Gen 6:4; Num 13:33, only). While some scholars
>   attempt to relate this term etymologically to *nāpal* I via the noun
>   *nēpel* “untimely birth” or “miscarriage” (as productive of superhuman
>   monstrosities), a more likely reconstruction is the proposal of a root
>   *nāpal* II, akin to other weak verbs, *pûl* II “be wonderful, strong,
>   mighty,” *pālāʾ* “be wonderful,” and even *pālâ* “separate, distinguish,”
>   *pālal* “discriminate.” This pattern of semantically related groups of
>   weak verbs with two strong consonants in common is a notably recurrent
>   phenomenon in Hebrew lexicography. Actually, the translation “giants”
>   is supported mainly by the LXX and may be quite misleading. The word
>   may be of unknown origin and mean “heroes” or “fierce warriors” etc.
>   The RSV and NIV transliteration “Nephilim” is safer and may be correct
>   in referring the noun to a race or nation.

### Of Rapha (רָפָא) and Rephaim (רְפָאִים):

These words seem clearly related as far as the Hebrew root goes (רפא). However, not all the lexicons necessarily seem to link what would seem to be the singular and the plural forms.

**(1) *The Hebrew and Aramaic Lexicon of the Old Testament*** (Ludwig Koehler, Walter Baumgartner, M. E. J. Richardson, and Johann Jakob Stamm).

For Rapha gives the following, and sees three different referents:

> רפא short form “he (יהוה/אֵל) has healed” ...
>   1. ... Sept. (acc.) Βαθρεφαν, the designation
>   of a place or a clan in Judah, constructed according to the name of an
>   ancestor ...
>   2. a son of Benjamin, a Benjaminite clan named after an ancestor ...
>   3. [notes only Hebrew construction and reference in 1 Ch 20:6, 8]

For Raphaim, they discuss it under the entry for Emeq (עֵמֶק; valley), without any elaboration.

**(2) *Enhanced Brown-Driver-Briggs Hebrew and English Lexicon*** (Francis Brown, Samuel Rolles Driver, and Charles Augustus Briggs)

For Rapha they simply list references, no elaboration.

For Rephaim, they give two entries (as there is apparently a homonym meaning "shades, ghosts"). The second relates to your question:

> old race of **giants** (perhaps = I. ר׳, as extinct and powerless; v.
>   especially WRS in Dr Dt 2:11; or as shadowy, vaguely known,
>   SchwallyZAW xviii (1896), 127 ff. v. also Stal.c.);—ancient inhab. of
>   Canaan ...

Even their second definition notes the possibility of "shadowy, vaguely known," which would seem to indicate possible closer connection to the homonym.

**(3) *Gesenius’ Hebrew and Chaldee Lexicon to the Old Testament Scriptures.*** (Wilhelm Gesenius and Samuel Prideaux Tregelles)

Of Rapha (second idea, as it notes homonym also) he mainly simply gives the references, but notes of 1 Chr 20:4 "the ancestor of the Canaanitish nation of the Rephaim."

Of Rephaim, he treats that both under the entry for Rapha and that of Emeq (עֵמֶק; valley). Under the first, he considers it related to the homonym idea and htus meanign "shades living in Hades," under the valley entry stating "('the valley of Rephaim'), southwest of Jerusalem, towards the land of the Philistines."

**(4) *Dictionary of Biblical Languages with Semantic Domains: Hebrew (Old Testament)*** (James Swanson)

For Rapha:

> 1. son of Benjamin (1Ch 8:2+) 2. one from Gath (1Ch 20:6, 8+), see also 8335; note: some sources translate as a common noun “giant;”
>      also, a part of a compound name, Beth *Rapha*

For Rephaim he relates it to the homonym idea:

> **the dead**, i.e., a class of beings that are the spirits of the
>   departed, with a focus on the beings as ghost-like, not having
>   material substance

He also notes the valley so named: "broad relatively flat valley about 2 mi. WSW of Jerusalem temple mount"

**(5) Article “2198 רָפָה.” (William White) in *Theological Wordbook of the Old Testament*** (Edited by R. Laird Harris, Gleason L. Archer Jr., and Bruce K. Waltke).

There is much discussed, both on the side of each word relating to "Ghosts of the dead, shades" and "**Giants**, Rephaim," with the latter considered for the references you gave. Of the giants, he states in part (note my last emphasized phrase):

> A term of Ugaritic origin, the designation for one of the most
>   primitive pre-Semitic peoples of Palestine. According to the Ugaritic
>   myths and legends the hero Danel (no relationship to the biblical
>   Daniel), and the champion of Baal are both called “Rephaites.” Whether
>   this is a folk etymology or a term based upon some ancient historical
>   term is unknown. The OT historians used it to describe the
>   pre-Israelite inhabitants of Palestine. Deuteronomy 2:20 mentions that
>   the Ammonites called them the “Zamzummim” but no data is extant on
>   this name. **The versions are confused in translating the term.**

Comment: @ScottS-WoW! You really put some effort into this one! I started to answer, and then got all wound up with different Targums, and realized I couldn't approach this topic being as linguistically challenged as I am. You explained the confusion, and gave a way to resolve it-kudos!

Comment: +1 Very helpful compendium - thanks, Scott. In addition to the lexica, the recent "Bible dictionaries" also have good discussions of the *[nephilim](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3260551)* and *[rephaim](http://goo.gl/9D1dJw)*. If of interest, see especially the *Dictionary of Deities and Demons in the Bible* entries, either by [Google Books preview](http://goo.gl/Wrk867) or [Amazon "Look Inside"](http://www.amazon.com/dp/0802824919/).

Answer (score 4):

There remains another possibility that does not appear coincidental. It has been argued that the morphology of *nephilim* as a Hebrew plural noun version of the verb *naphal* is impossible. As such, the only two options would be renderings of *nophelim* and *nephulim*. Therefore, *nephilim* would not be a proper Hebrew word. Interestingly, if one examines Aramaic, which uses the same alphabet, an extremely similar word does exist. That being *nephilin*. Guess what it means in Aramaic? Giant.

It would seem plausible that the Hebrews borrowed the Aramaic word and changed the "n" to an "m" at the end. There are several Hebrew and ancient language scholars who argue for this. Michael S. Heiser is one who is still around and lights out with the material.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean by "lights out with the material, but otherwise a nicely supported answer, Bigern. Welcome to the forum. Best wishes,

Comment: Nice, if that so we can say that למידים can not exist and it's only Lemudim or Lomdim? Cause if we can understand that Lemidim are people who can learn, so we can also say that נפילים are people who can fall (from heaven/sky/etc..). Anyway +1 for nice answer, and welcome!